# Toddler song about heaven

Tags: heaven, children, identify-this

I'm looking for the name and singer/composer of a toddler song.  The words I remember are " Tap tap tap, tap tap tap, someone's building  up a place for me....building me a home in heaven.  Jesus, building me a home in heaven, Jesus building me a home in heaven...."  It was a great song to do with motions similar to the wise man built his house upon the rock.  I can't find or remember enough of the song.  It could be from the late 80s or early 90s.  Thanks.

Comment: Neither Duckduckgo nor Google had a second hit for the quoted phrase, "Jesus building me a home in heaven". This could be hard to answer. If you remember any more details, comment on and/or add them to your question, and we'll hope someone else reads this who remembers the song.

Comment: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=mLATrOoPBqM

Comment: Where were you when you heard this song (state/country)?

Answer (score 3):

*Tap Tap Tap* by Maranatha Kids on the Album Tiny Tots Pwaise vol 6
(https://music.apple.com/pg/album/tiny-tot-pwaise-vol-6/715831200)